# Recuperar maior e menor hora condicionadas a datas

Tags: sql, oracle

Dentro de uma tabela contendo as colunas `data_inicio`, `data_fim`, `hora_inicio`, `hora_fim` preciso identificar dentro de um conjunto de registros as seguintes ocorrências: a data início menor, a data final maior, a hora inicial menor e a hora final maior.

A imagem abaixo lista um conjunto de registros no qual quero fazer a verificação de menor data_inicio, maior data_fim, menor hora_inicio, maior hora_fim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com base nos registros apresentados na imagem acima,  a menor data início é simples de conseguir, bastando para isso simplesmente usar o operador **MIN**. O mesmo ocorre para obter a maior data fim. Preciso somente usar o operador **MAX** para obtê-la. Para calcular a maior hora inicial e a menor hora final não posso usar a mesma abordagem como pode ser visto no resultado do sql abaixo.

**SQL:**

```
select min(data_inicio), max(data_fim), min(hora_inicio), max(hora_fim)
from minha_tabela
where codigo = 2
```

**Resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para calcular, tanto a menor hora inicio quanto a maior hora final preciso levar em consideração mais do que simplesmente a própria coluna. Simplesmente usar o operador **MIN** e **MAX** não resolve. Preciso levar em consideração também as colunas de datas. Olhando a primeira imagem nós podemos perceber que a menor hora início é '1000', pois a menor data é '04/05'. A maior hora final é '1900', pois a maior data final é '20/05'.

**Há como implementar esse tipo de consulta simplesmente por meio de SQL? Se sim, como?**

Este exemplo está no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5450/1)**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente deve concatenar as colunas de data e hora para transformar a string em data:

```
to_date(data_inicio || ' ' || hora_inicio,'dd-mm-yy hh24mi'))
```

Após isso basta pegar a menor e a maior data:

```
min(to_date(data_inicio || ' ' || hora_inicio,'dd-mm-yy hh24mi')),
max(to_date(data_fim || ' ' || hora_fim,'dd-mm-yy hh24mi'))
```

E para separar novamente em apenas data e/ou hora:

```
to_char(min_inicio,'dd/mm/yyyy') menor_data,
to_char(min_inicio,'hh24:mi:ss') menor_hora,
to_char(max_fim,'dd/mm/yyyy') maior_data,
to_char(max_fim,'hh24:mi:ss') maior_hora
```

Veja exemplo funcionando no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d1f13/34/0).

Comment: Lúcio, acabei por criar meu exemplo no SQL Fiddle com o banco MySQL o que levou você a criar a sua resposta com base nesse banco. Tem como você adaptar sua resposta para o Oracle. Use esse SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d1f13.

Comment: @GeisonSantos Editei a resposta!

Comment: Lúcio, parabéns! Muito boa a sua solução. Tinha conseguido de uma outra forma um pouco mais verbosa. Enfim, sua solução ficou melhor. Vou postar minha resposta depois para mostrar aos outros uma outra alternativa.

Comment: Valeu cara :) @GeisonSantos

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi o problema, apenas agrupar por código pode resolver:

```
select min(data_inicio), max(data_fim), min(hora_inicio), max(hora_fim)
from minha_tabela
where codigo = 2
group by codigo
```

Comment: Cigano, não é tão simples assim. O resultado que você postou é o mesmo do exemplo dado, portanto não esperado.

Comment: Não está claro o que você quer. Repare que nem o exemplo que você colocou faz sentido. No segundo registro (primeira foto) a data final é 19 de abril. Você quer um registro apenas com a menor data e hora iniciais e maior data e hora finais, ou quer outra coisa?

Comment: A primeira imagem corresponde ao escopo ou conjunto de registros que eu devo usar para fazer a verificação da data inicio maior, data fim maior, hora_inicio menor e hora_fim maior. Serve somente para ilustrar o universo pesquisado. Portanto, não precisa estar ordenado.

Comment: Fiz um ajuste na pergunta para melhorar a compreensão.

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra alternativa, um pouco mais verbosa, para solucionar este problema é o uso de uma tabela temporária. Inicialmente recuperamos esta tabela somente com as informações de data início miníma e data final máxima.

```
with limites as (
   select min(data_inicio) data_minima, max(data_fim) data_maxima
   from minha_tabela
   where codigo = 2
)
```

Em seguida nós fazemos a junção desta tabela com a tabela pesquisada para recuperar a hora mínima e a hora máxima. Isso é necessário devido a condicionalidade dos campos de hora aos de data como já foi descrito na pergunta. Esta junção é necessária, pois podemos ter mais de uma data igual tanto para o valor mínimo quanto para o valor máximo. Como podemos observar na imagem abaixo, temos três valores para o dia 03 de maio e dois para o dia 30 de maio:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para a **hora início miníma** teríamos:

```
(
  select min(hora_inicio) from minha_tabela
  inner join limites on limites.data_minima = data_inicio
  where codigo = 2
) as hora_minima
```

Para a **hora final máxima** teríamos:

```
(
  select max(hora_fim) from minha_tabela
  inner join limites on limites.data_maxima = data_fim
  where codigo = 2
) as hora_maxima
```

A SQL com a solução [completa](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/46ef01/2) ficaria assim:

```
with limites as (
    select min(data_inicio) data_minima, max(data_fim) data_maxima
    from minha_tabela
    where codigo = 2
)
select (
  select data_minima from limites
) as data_minima,
(
  select data_maxima from limites
) as data_maxima,
(
  select min(hora_inicio) from minha_tabela
  inner join limites on limites.data_minima = data_inicio
  where codigo = 2
) as hora_minima,
(
  select max(hora_fim) from minha_tabela
  inner join limites on limites.data_maxima = data_fim
  where codigo = 2
) as hora_maxima
from dual
```

**Resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]